# Right join returning results not in the where set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't understand why right join is not returning results as expected.

Where condition cleary says return only results with:

```
R.REIN_SRT = 'A' AND R.REIN_STA = '9'
```

but instead, it returns everything in table, just like there is no where condition:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
| INVE_KEY |  INVE_NME   | INVE_KEY | REIN_SRT | REIN_STA |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
| NULL     | NULL        |        1 | S        |        1 |
| 1        | CHAIR BLACK |        1 | A        |        9 |
| NULL     | NULL        |        1 | B        |        2 |
| NULL     | NULL        |        1 | S        |        1 |
| NULL     | NULL        |        1 | S        |        1 |
| NULL     | NULL        |        1 | S        |        1 |
| NULL     | NULL        |        1 | S        |        1 |
| NULL     | NULL        |        1 | S        |        1 |
| NULL     | NULL        |        1 | S        |        1 |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Why is where condition not working as expected?

Here is the whole example:

```
DECLARE @JEINVE TABLE
(
INVE_KEY INT,
INVE_NME VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @JEREIN TABLE
(
INVE_KEY INT,
REIN_SRT CHAR(1),
REIN_STA CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @JEINVE(INVE_KEY, INVE_NME)
VALUES(1, 'CHAIR BLACK'),(2, 'WHITE TABLE'),(3, 'BLACK CANDLE')

INSERT INTO @JEREIN(INVE_KEY,REIN_SRT,REIN_STA)
VALUES(1,'S','1'),(1,'A','9'),(1,'B','2'),(1,'S','1'),(1,'S','1'),(1,'S','1'),(1,'S','1'),(1,'S','1'),(1,'S','1')

SELECT *
FROM @JEINVE INVE RIGHT JOIN @JEREIN R
ON INVE.INVE_KEY = R.INVE_KEY
AND R.REIN_SRT = 'A' AND R.REIN_STA = '9'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @JEINVE INVE 
RIGHT JOIN @JEREIN R
ON INVE.INVE_KEY = R.INVE_KEY
WHERE R.REIN_SRT = 'A' AND R.REIN_STA = '9'
```

Change in your query:

Existing

```
AND R.REIN_SRT = 'A' AND R.REIN_STA = '9'
```

New:

```
WHERE R.REIN_SRT = 'A' AND R.REIN_STA = '9'
```

Explanation:

When you put the condition in "ON CLAUSE"

- In right join it will consider, whether or not to pull the data from RIGHT Table

But when you put the condition in "WHERE Clause"

- In this case, it will filter the rows as per your condition

Comment: Is there explanation missing?

Comment: Completed the answer!

Comment: This is really interesting - with this: ON INVE.INVE_KEY = R.INVE_KEY AND R.REIN_SRT = 'A'  - it seems like everything after AND is not part of condition.